# Correspondence between fundamental group and geometric properties of $X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, gt.geometric-topology

At the time of studing some algebraic topology I was wondering about the following.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\pi_1(X)$ be its fundamental group.

If we assume some algebraic property of $\pi_1(X)$ like it is a solvable group or nilpotent group then can we conclude some topological or geometric property of $X$?

In a broad sence is there any relationship between the algebraic properties of fundamental group or higher homotopy group with some geometric or topological properties of the space?

If anyone provides any kind of references regarding these it will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $X$ is just a general topological space, it's not clear what you mean by "geometric" property and whether it's distinct from a topological property. The fundamental group affects other algebraic invariants of $X$, such as the first homology group, or via the Hurewicz or Freudenthal suspension theorems. The fundamental group determines a compact connected surface up to isomorphism. There is also the Mostow rigidity theorem which says a certain class of manifolds are totally determined by their fundamental group.

Comment: For a general topological space, it's probable that every property of $X$ which is determined by the fundamental group structure can be phrased as a property of $X$'s algebraic invariants. For a manifold or CW complex or something with additional structure, you can get more specific about "geometric" properties. Ultimately what the fundamental group controls is covers, and these provide a more geometric interpretation than the definition via loops.

Comment: In the case of regular metric spaces the fundamental group influences the purely metric properties of the space as geometric homogeneity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with a presentation of the fundamental group of a (nice) space, then you can build a 2-dimensional CW-complex from the presentation that has the same fundamental group. This means that the answer to a simple interpretation of your question is negative, as the geometric / properties properties of that space could vary a lot within the homotopy type, but that is not the end of the story.

If you know that $X$ has some nice geometric properties, (see [hyperbolic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) in Wikipedia), then sometimes that has very significant reprecussions for the algebraic structure of $\pi_1(X)$. A good place to start for this would be by skimming some of the books and survey articles on Geometric Group Theory. (You could start with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_theory). Sometimes various variants of the fundamental group need studying especially for non-compact manifolds where discussion of phenomena related to 'ends' becomes important.

The point about the presentation is that going back from the algebra of $\pi_1(X)$ to properties of $X$ is likely to be harder. The structure is reflected at a *homotopical* level, so you need homotopical analogues of nilpotency or solvablity.  These do exist but are quite subtle.

Comment: Can you provide some reference for homotopical analogues of nilpotency Or solvability?

Comment: A good place to start is with the [nLab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nilpotent+topological+space). The references at the end are all good ones. I cannot find explicit mention of the corresponding spatial analogues of solvable groups, but the references may mention that case.

Comment: I don't get why "you need homotopical analogues of nilpotency or solvablity." Homotopy equivalent pointed spaces have isomorphic fundamental groups, and solvability is already an isomorphism-invariant. Do you mean a homotopy invariant property of spaces which is equivalent to solvablity of the fundamental groups? I mean yes, this was the question... You didn't answer it, right?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, you are right. I mean some homotopy invariant property of spaces which is equivalent to solvability of fundamental bgroups.